# Cakephp Files and Folder class with regex to search for file

Tags: regex, cakephp

I am creating some sort of shell for removing backup files. I use to create backup of original file using keyword 'bkp'. It could be anywhre in file name either like this **["abc.bkp.ctp", "abc-bkp.ctp", abc_bkp.ctp", "bkp_abc.ctp"]**. I mean any way. I wish to remove all files using shell. I am using Cakephp's Files N Folder Class "http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html". How would I write regex to search for these files.

Whats my shell logic is.

```
    public function removeBkp() {
        $path = BASE_PATH . DS . APP_DIR . DS;
        $count = 0;

        $this->out("", 2);
        $this->out("-------------------------------------", 1);
        $this->out("Path : " . $path, 1);
        $this->out("FILES DETAILS", 1);
        $this->out("-------------------------------------", 2);
        $dir = new Folder($path);
        // Need to seach bkp files here 
        $defaultFiles = $dir->findRecursive("(bkp)");

        $results = $defaultFiles;
        if ($results == null || empty($results)) {
            $this->out("No file to delete.", 3);
        } else {
            foreach ($results as $file) {
                // unlink($file);
                $this->out("File removed - " . $file, 1);
                $count++;
            }
            $this->out("Total files: " . count($results), 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something like `.*bkp.*[.]ctp` should do. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dS6mY6/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all filenames with this regex:

```
([\w._-]*bkp[\S]*?\.ctp)
```

Assuming only `._-` are used to split the files up, you may need to add more to that character class.

This regex also assumes that the file always ends with ctp.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tB9nM9/1

EDIT: If you wish to match any extension, you can generalise the extension with `\w{3}`. Where 3 is the length, you can add variance here if needed, but more specific is usually better.

```
([\w._-]*bkp[\S]*\.\w{3})
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/tB9nM9/2

Comment: If I wish to do it for any extension not specific to ctp.

Comment: You could replace `ctp` with a regex to match 3 chars. I'll make an update for that.

Comment: **([\w._-]*bkp[\S]*)**. Done it with this. Thanks

Comment: That will work, yes. I would encourage you to determine which filetypes you wish to match and include them in an alternating pattern, though. That way you have better control over what you are targeting. From the first, replace `ctp` with `(?:ctp|php|sql)` or whatever else you need.

Comment: I wish to take lesson of regex from you. 1 thing in programming I am always confused and scared of. (Y)